# Customize textfield validator error message

Tags: extjs4

I want to change the red line that appear in a textfield when we add validator to this like:

```
$allowblank : false,
```

Instead I want that a short text appear beside the textfield or a small popup linked to the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, after the 'onReady' :

```
        Ext.QuickTips.init();
```

This will show a small pop-up.

See if it can respond to your needs in the way you want.

Comment: I am using "Ext.application" in a MVC application, I have app.js and views folder that contains the views of the application, one of this views is a form whith a textfield, so I don't know where to place "Ext.QuickTips.init();"

Comment: I think @sha is right, you will have to extend a class to add a specific way to deal with a pop up as shown on his picture, wich is the result of code line I gave. I don't know where you could put it on a MVC though.
Unfortunately I don't know what will have to be added/modified to get the result you need.
I'll look for a solution as soon as I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this [image] would be enough for you? it's basically an icon and a message text appears when you hover you mouse over this icon.

This can be easily achieved by specifying msgTarget: 'side' for each field.

Comment: Thanks for you replay, yes this is the default validator message, what I look for is a bit diffent I want that the message appear automatically, is this possible?

Comment: You don't want to have a modal popup, because it will distract user a LOT... Another example is here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/statusbar/statusbar-advanced.html - they have a status bar visible with error message. If you need anything else - I'm afraid you will have to re-write or extend couple components (which is not a big deal at all)